# Why undo log entries in MySQL innodb buffer pool (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona, xtradb, mysql-innodb-cluster

Long transactions generate several old versions of the rows in the undo log which are stored in ibdata file.Is there any possibility that undo log entries are also stored in the innodb buffer pool.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be stored "permanently" in the buffer_pool because it is lost in a power failure.  Undo is needed then, too.